# Passing arguments to ENTRYPOINT causes the container to start and run indefinitely

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra, command-line-arguments

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db_cassandra:
    container_name: db_cassandra
    image: cassandra:latest
    volumes:
      - "./common/cassandra:/lua/cassandra_setup:rw"
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u", "cassandra", "-p", "cassandra" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  remote_cassandra:
    container_name: remote_cassandra
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./it/remote_cassandra/Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: cassandra:latest
    depends_on:
      dd_cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - "./common/cassandra:/lua/cassandra_setup:rw"
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
```

Here's the `remote_cassandra/Dockerfile`:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

COPY ./it/common/cassandra/cassandra-setup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /cassandra-setup.sh

CMD ["/cassandra-setup.sh", "db_cassandra"]
```

`remote_cassandra` remotely connects to the `db_cassandra` service and executes certain queries.

Here's how the `cassandra-setup.sh` script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#code that creates schema.cql
.
.
.
DB_CONTAINER="$1"
while ! cqlsh $DB_CONTAINER 9042 -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "waiting for db_cassandra to be up..."
  sleep .5
done
cqlsh $DB_CONTAINER 9042 -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
```

When I pass the "dd_cassandra" as an argument to ENTRYPOINT, the docker containers are created and nothing happens after that, they keep waiting indefinitely.

However, if I don't pass the argument and simply hardcode it in the `cassandra-setup.sh` script like this below, then things run smoothly:

```
#!/bin/bash
#code that creates schema.cql
.
.
.

while ! cqlsh db_cassandra 9042 -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "waiting for db_cassandra to be up..."
  sleep .5
done
cqlsh db_cassandra 9042 -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
```

I've also tried with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/cassandra-setup.sh"]
CMD ["db_cassandra"]
```

and it doesn't work too.